# RTL8139 not being detected on openSUSE 11.3 - can installing openSUSE 11.0 on VirtualBox help?

Tags: networking, opensuse, hardware, realtek

[http://en.opensuse.org/HCL:Network_(Wired)](http://en.opensuse.org/HCL%3aNetwork_%28Wired%29)

This hardware is getting shown in BIOS, but lspci dosn't show it on `openSUSE 11.3`.
So, if I plant `openSUSE 11.0` on the VirtualBox on `11.3`, will that get it detected or it is compulsory for me to install the `11.0` separately?

Comment: Have you tried that card in an different PC? Or Tried other PCI sockets? I suspect you have some hardware trouble.

Comment: @Tim if you see the link in OP you'll find that they haven't mentioned 8139 w.r.t 11.3.

Comment: @Tim Now I realize that the hardware I was using wasn't RTL8139 :doh:, and it is this hardware that wasn't  being recognized in the bios itself. So, perhaps Suse wasn't at fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VirtualBox/VMVare/SomeVM is useless in this case.

VirtualBoxes see only "emulated" network cards. There is no way a VM can manage a real ethernet card.